# Shared object between multiple JInternalFrames

Tags: java, datamodel, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

What's the most efficient method of implementing a shared data object between multiple JInternalFrames on a single JDesktopPane?

Not sure whether to go with singleton or can I put a data object in the JDesktopPane and access from a component?  I don't want to keep separate instances of this data for each frame (lots of frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would steer clear of singleton (as it's a-kin to using global variables - See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for a description) and instead subclass `JInternalFrame` to contain a reference to the shared data object; e.g.

```
public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
  private final SharedData data;

  public MyInternalFrame(SharedData data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Obviously despite having multiple references to your SharedData (one per MyInternalFrame instance) there is still only one `SharedData` object in your system; i.e. you are not duplicating data with this approach.